# Question is not a duplicate

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

[Screaming Frog hreflang missing confirmation links](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/116930/screaming-frog-hreflang-missing-confirmation-links)

Is not the same question as [Missing confirmation link for the hreflang x-default element](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/104490/missing-confirmation-link-for-the-hreflang-x-default-element)

and the answer is also not relevent to the specific question.

Answer (score 1):

Both questions are titled "Missing confirmation link for hreflang" as reported by Screaming Frog crawler.  That sounds pretty duplicate to me.

If there are multiple possible solutions to the same problem, they should probably be merged into one question so that people can find all the answers in one place.

If the questions are not duplicate, you need to edit the questions to differentiate them from the other.  The title especially should show the differentiation.   Once a duplicate is edited, it automatically enters the re-open queue.   You could also flag it for moderator attention.

EDIT:  I've edited the titles of the questions and re-opened them.  The titles are now clearly differentiated to me:

- [Screaming Frog hreflang missing confirmation links for rel=“alternative”](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/116930/screaming-frog-hreflang-missing-confirmation-links-for-rel-alternative)
- [Screaming Frog reports missing confirmation link when the hreflang x-default element is the same in all pages](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/104490/screaming-frog-reports-missing-confirmation-link-when-the-hreflang-x-default-ele)

Comment: Whilst those two questions _result_ in the same problem ("missing confirmation link") - so there are certainly similarities - the "duplicate target" is primarily concerned with a miss-understanding of the "x-default" attribute value (and "x-default" is included in the title). Whereas the question highlighted here would seem to be caused by a fundamental HTML syntax error that would have been picked up _earlier_ by an HTML validator - the "missing confirmation link" is almost secondary in this instance (although that is the net result).

Comment: Any suggestion on how the to could be edited to clarify differences?

Comment: I'm not sure how they can be edited to "clarify differences". IMO, they already are sufficiently different.

Comment: The questions don't need to be edited IMO, they are clearly different.  One is specific to hreflang="x-default", the other is not, and that is reflected int the titles too.